# Inserting several lines in determined places of a 3D plot

Tags: plotting

I have a special list instead of which I create another one by a `Table`

```
data = Table[{x, y, Cos[x] Sin[y]}, {x, 0, π, 0.1}, {y, 0, 2 π, 0.2}];
```

It can be plotted by `ListPlot3D` as

```
ListPlot3D[Flatten[data, 1]]
```

How I insert some lines according to several determined numbers of `y` axis? (As I shown in the below plot in which I inserted them manually)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = Table[{x, y, Cos[x] Sin[y]}, {x, 0, π, 0.1}, {y, 0,  2 π, 0.2}];
```

1. You can create `Graphics3D` object with desired lines and use `Show` to combine it with `ListPlot3D`:

```
lines = Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, Line[{{Pi, #, -1}, {Pi, #, 1}}] & /@ {2, 3, 5}}];
Show[ListPlot3D[Flatten[data, 1]], lines]
```

[image]

2. Alternatively, and more conveniently, you can use [`FaceGrids`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FaceGrids.html) and [`FaceGridsStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FaceGridsStyle.html):

[image]

```
ListPlot3D[Flatten[data, 1], 
 FaceGrids -> {{{1, 0, 0}, {{2, 3, {5,Directive[ Green, Dashed, Thick]}}, {}}}}, 
 FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

[image]

Use `FaceGrids -> {{{-1, 0, 0}, {{2, 3, 5}, {}}}}` to get

[image]

and `FaceGrids -> {{{-1, 0, 0}, {{},{-1/2,0,3/4}}}}` to get

[image]

`FaceGrids -> {{{0, -1, 0}, {{1,2,3/2, 5/2}, {}}}}` gives

[image]

and `FaceGrids -> {{{0, 1, 0}, {{1,2,3/2, 5/2}, {}}}}` gives

[image]

Comment: I had asked a question and after that I found its answer

Comment: For this reason I deleted that in the comments